# Proteger pasta contra acesso direto

Tags: php, segurança, upload

O utilizador precisa de logar para ter acesso a uma lista de documentos.

Todos os documentos estão na pasta "/uploads".

Quando se conhece o diretorio, é fácil ter acesso a ele, basta digitar no browser 'dominio.com/uploads'.

O que fazer para proteger os arquivos contra acesso direto e permitir o download apenas dentro do sistema?

Tenho algumas ideias, mas não sei se serão suficientes:

- Utilizar o robots para evitar indexação pelos motores de busca.
- Dar nomes complexos aos ficheiros de modo a evitar download por tentativa erro.
- Proteger pasta com .htpass e .htaccess (não sei qual impacto depois para o PHP conseguir ter acesso a pasta).
- Modificar o sistema e substituir o link direto por um botão download, assim o diretório não é exposto.

Comment: Deixe a pasta com arquivos sensíveis fora do acesso público (public_html, www, htdocs) e faça um script PHP que busque esses arquivos e disponibilize para download.

Comment: @AdirKuhn mas o PHP não tem permissão para aceder pastas fora da raíz. Se alterar as permissões, não estarei a criar um problema ainda maior?

Comment: Acho que sua última ideia é a melhor e suficiente.

Comment: Normalmente se tem acesso a um nível acima da public_html, agora se você não tem vai ter que utilizar outra solução.

Comment: Usar o .htaccess é uma saída. O PHP continuará acessando a pasta mas pelo navegador o apache não vai permitir o acesso direto. Porém terá que criar um script no PHP para efetuar o download.

Answer (score 4):

Depende do que você quer. Cada arquivo pertence a um único utilizador, e seria ruim se um utilizador acessasse os arquivos de outro? Se uma pessoa com acesso a um arquivo passasse o link para outra, não autorizada, isso seria um problema? Etc.

Alguns comentários sobre suas propostas:

> - Utilizar o robots para evitar indexação pelos motores de busca.

Isso só vai impedir que os *crawlers* **que respeitam o `robots.txt`** indexem seus arquivos - isso não terá efeito algum naqueles que não respeitam (se houver algum) nem impedirá que qualquer usuário em particular acesse esses arquivos. Não que seja ruim fazer isso, apenas insuficiente...

Da mesma forma, impedir que seu *webserver* retorne índices (ex.: ao acessar `dominio.com/uploads/` ele te dá uma lista de todos os arquivos na pasta `uploads`) - desabilitando a [opção `Indexes`](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings) - também ajuda a dificultar que um visitante descubra quais arquivos estão lá, mas também não impede alguém com um link de baixá-lo.

> - Dar nomes complexos aos ficheiros de modo a evitar download por tentativa erro.

Essa pode ser uma técnica apropriada, dependendo dos seus requisitos de segurança (ver início da resposta). Uma maneira de implementar é criar um link contendo um [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) e/ou o *hash* do arquivo, e permitir que qualquer um que tenha acesso ao link baixe o arquivo. Naturalmente, seu PHP somente entregará o link para os usuários logados, e se um deles repassar/publicar o link isso não é muito diferente dele simplesmente copiar e entregar o arquivo a terceiros...

(o maior problema dessa técnica é de "relações públicas" - nós sabemos que "adivinhar" um UUID é totalmente impraticável, mas pessoas sem conhecimento técnico tendem a pensar "ah, mas e se alguém descobrir o link? não é mais seguro proteger com senha?"...)

> - Proteger pasta com .htpass e .htaccess (não sei qual impacto depois para o PHP conseguir ter acesso a pasta).

Não tenho experiência com PHP, mas creio que não há impacto algum para que ele acesse a pasta (isso é mais uma questão do `Directory` do Apache). Quanto à eficácia, assumindo que você esteja usando HTTPS e que seu *webserver* esteja configurado corretamente (não expondo arquivos `.ht*` aos usuários - o que é padrão no Apache) é uma abordagem relativamente segura. Os únicos problemas, segundo [essa resposta no security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/9383/6939), são de usabilidade (não é exatamente o método mais *user-friendly*) e a falta de uma proteção mais forte contra ataques de força bruta.

> - Modificar o sistema e substituir o link direto por um botão download, assim o diretório não é exposto.

Essa é a maneira mais "garantida", ainda que mais chata de implementar e possivelmente com a pior performance (não necessariamente algo inaceitável). Seria necessário manter a pasta `uploads` inacessível (o meio não importa: colocá-la fora do `public_html`, usar `.htaccess`, usar `mod_rewrite`, etc) e criar um script `downloads.php` - que poderia combinar uma verificação de acesso tal como [sugerido na resposta do Lollipop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53004/215) com o uso de [`header` e `readfile`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) (**atualização:** a performance dessa segunda parte pode ser bastante melhorada através do uso de [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/); mais detalhes [aqui](http://blog.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-x-sendfile/)).

Feito isso, você tem total controle sobre a forma de autenticação, os *throttles* aplicáveis, etc. Muito provavelmente esta é a forma mais segura e que provê a melhor experiência de usuário. Caso alguma das opções anteriores não seja "boa o bastante" para seus requisitos específicos, essa é a maneira que eu sugeriria.

Comment: Obrigado. Sim, cada arquivo pertence a um único utilizador, e seria ruim se um utilizador acessasse os arquivos de outro. A soluções foram implementadas, apenas gostaria de uma segunda opinião para saber se seriam suficientes para uma protecção mínima.

Answer (score 2):

Tenho uma forma que pode ser uma alternativa viável. Utilize: **$_SESSION** para validar o acesso a `index.php` do `dominio.com/uploads`. No entanto, antes, você precisa fazer isto no .htacess, para evitar o acesso direto aos arquivos:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.pdf$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dominio.com/login.php$1 [L]
```

Na tela de login, depois da autenticação você faria isto:

```
...

session_start();

$_SESSION['estoulogado'] = 1;

...
```

Lá em **dominio.com/uploads** você teria algo como isto:

```
...

session_start();

if ($_SESSION['estoulogado'] != 1) {
    header("Location: http://dominio.com/login.php");
} else { 

$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$idusername = $_SESSION['iduser'];

}

...

CÓDIGO DA PÁGINA DE DOWNLOAD

...
```

Comment: Obrigado. Na verdade o sistema de autenticação já está feito e o download é realizado através do uso do header e readfile, apenas gostaria de saber se havia outras soluções. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: acho que ele quer impedir a listagem dos arquivos pois provavelmente está sem um "index.php" ou sem bloqueio do option indexes..

Comment: Filipe, se vc já está usando header e readfile então seria muito mais prático colocar os arquivos num diretório privado, fora da pasta pública.. entendeu ? Aliás, usar header e readfile para download de um arquivo físico no disco não é algo muito adequado por questão de performance, etc.. mas isso não é o foco em questão.. pode-se discutir numa outra oportunidade.. apenas deixo essa dica.

Answer (score -1):

Crie um `index.php` dentro da pasta, neste arquivo redirecione para um local seguro, tipo a home do seu site.

```
<?php header("location: ../views/home.php");?>
```